# C# static abstract properties cannot be overwritten by child interface

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I am trying to work with static abstract properties that were introduced in .NET 7.
here is an example of what i am trying to achieve:

```
public interface IRegister
{
    public static abstract byte RegisterCode { get; }
    public static abstract int BitsSize { get; }
}

public interface IRegister8Bit : IRegister
{
    public static new int BitsSize => 8;
}

public class T : IRegister
{
    public static byte RegisterCode => 0x01;
    public static int BitsSize => 16;
}

public class T2 : IRegister8Bit
{
    public static byte RegisterCode => 0x07;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Test<Register>() where Register : IRegister
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Register.RegisterCode);
        Console.WriteLine(Register.BitsSize);
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test<T>();
        Test<T2>();
    }
}
```

But I get the following compile error:

> Compilation error (line 20, col 19): 'T2' does not implement interface
> member 'IRegister.BitsSize'

why is T2 still requesting me to explicitly implement BitsSize even though it is implemented in the parent interface IRegister8Bit ?

Comment: `public static new int BitsSize => 8;` why `new`?

Comment: _"even though it is implemented in the parent interface IRegister8Bit"_  - [it's not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords).

Comment: Hint, the error is complaining about the `T2` class not implementing _`IRegister`_'s property, not `IRegister8Bit`'s property.

Comment: `public static new int BitsSize => 8;` in `IRegister8Bit` isn't doing anything, you should remove it. There seems to be no way to explicitly override and implement an abstract static method in a derived interface, only a derived class.

Comment: @Charlieface without the new there is warning saying the property will hide its parent and that it is not explicit so new should be added if hiding is intended.

I was afraid of that, would have been nice if there was the ability to provide a default implementation in a derived interface.

Comment: And this is another reason why the `new` operator for shadowing (why didn't they call it `shadows`?) is a bad idea. There are very few times - if ever - that it makes sense to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) for the static abstract method:

```
public interface IRegister8Bit : IRegister
{
     static int IRegister.BitsSize => 8;
}
```

Then `T2` will compile:

```
public class T2 : IRegister8Bit
{
    public static byte RegisterCode => 0x07;
}
```

This has downside though, `BitsSize` will not be accessible by the type name so the generic indirection approach should be used:

```
// for T both props work
Console.WriteLine(T.RegisterCode);
Console.WriteLine(T.BitsSize);

// for T2 only RegisterCode is accessible:
Console.WriteLine(T2.RegisterCode);
// Console.WriteLine(T2.BitsSize); // will not compile
Console.WriteLine(GetBitSize<T2>());

// generic indirection method:
int GetBitSize<T>() where T : IRegister => T.BitsSize;
```